# IIS 408 Logging

Tags: iis

We have some web systems that in the past have experienced HTTP 408 response codes when making a request. They can happen at any time, there doesn't seem to be any pattern to them.

The problem we have is that the client request goes through a TMG gateway, and IIS never logs the 408. The last request I see is a 200, and subsequently a client received a 408.

Do 408's make it to IIS logs, or are 408's higher up in the stack meaning the request never makes it to IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All http responses are at the same level. They are all at the application level since http is an application level protocol.

Most likely it's TMG returning the 408 and the request is not getting to IIS. Look in the TMG logs, you should see them. IIS logs everything so if you don't see it in the IIS logs then the requests are either not making it there or you're looking in the wrong place for the log data.

Comment: Yup, cheers for this. Thought I'd double check: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpLogging where it states `By default, HTTP logging is enabled for all requests on Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.`